# Lock views in orthographic mode

Tags: 3d-view, workflow

Is there a way to lock orthographic views in Blender 2.8?

Kind regards,

Andre

Answer (score 3):

You can disable automatic switching to perspective from orthographic via preferences:

- Menus → Edit → Preferences → Navigation → Orbit & Pan → Auto Perspective (remove tick).

I personally make use of Quad View, which splits the viewport into four regions: Top Orthographic, Front Orthographic, Right Orthographic and User Perspective. Also handy to enable "box" mode so any zoom / pan done in one area is synchronised with the others:

- Menus → View → Area → Toggle Quad View
- Sidebar → View → Quad View → Box

[image]